# How to append 'explode'd columns to a dataframe keeping all existing columns?

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to add exploded columns to a dataframe:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
 
# Convenience function for turning JSON strings into DataFrames.
def jsonToDataFrame(json, schema=None):
  # SparkSessions are available with Spark 2.0+
  reader = spark.read
  if schema:
    reader.schema(schema)
  return reader.json(sc.parallelize([json]))

schema = StructType().add("a", MapType(StringType(), IntegerType()))
 
events = jsonToDataFrame("""
{
  "a": {
    "b": 1,
    "c": 2
  }
}
""", schema)
 
display(
  events.withColumn("a", explode("a").alias("x", "y"))
)
```

However, I'm hitting the following error:

```
AnalysisException: The number of aliases supplied in the AS clause does not match the number of columns output by the UDTF expected 2 aliases but got a
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I used the following:

```
display(
  events.select(explode("a").alias("x", "y"), *[c for c in events.columns])
)
```

This approach uses `select` to specify the columns to return.

The first argument explodes the data:

```
explode("a").alias("x", "y")
```

The second argument specifies all existing columns should be included in the select:\

```
*[c for c in events.columns]
```

Note that I'm prefixing the list with `*` - this sends each column name as a separate parameter.

---

**Simpler Method**

The [API docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.select.html) specify:

```
Parameters
colsstr, Column, or list
column names (string) or expressions (Column). If one of the column names is ‘*’, that column is expanded to include all columns in the current DataFrame.
```

We can simplify the first approach by passing in "*" to select all the columns:

```
display(
  events.select("*", explode("a").alias("x", "y"))
)
```